# Enforcing event handling wireup

Tags: c#, events, language-agnostic, programming-languages, delegates

Is there a way to perform compile time enforcement of event handling wireup?

So for example lets say I have a class that exposes the standard `EventHandler<T>` can I ensure that any instantiated instances of this class have the `OnMyEvent` handler, handled? (Preferably at compile time)

The only way I can see of performing this is through either having an eventhandler as part of the objects constructor or using reflection at runtime. Are there any alternatives?

Also, if C# doesn't allow for this functionality; out of curiosity do any other languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events are *usually* intended for ***optional*** consumption by the calling code of the object - for example, as an observer (or multiple observers). It is pretty rare that handling the event is *enforced*. There is no standard language / compiler construct for verifying an event gets subscribed at compile-time (and I suspect it would be very hard, since you could validly subscribe/unsubscribe at any time, at any place in the code - possibly multiple times, i.e. +HandlerA, +HandlerB, -HandlerA, -HandlerB - which ends with no subscribers).

In the scenario you present, where it is *required*, then passing it in to the constructor sounds more appropriate, but I would probably use `Func<...>` or `Action<...>` in this case (not `EventHandler<T>`). But that is subjective.

Other approaches:

- make it an abstract class and force the consumer to subclass and `override` one-or-more `abstract` members
- have an `interface` parameter that the consumer must supply

Comment: +1 for addressing some root issues and misconceptions that the OP has. I'll also add that if you have a build script that runs unit tests after build, you can enforce many things during the build process that the compiler alone cannot.